# Check if placeholder text already exists within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an #error paragraph. Everytime there is an error within the form on submit. The inputs placeholder text gets added to the #error paragraph.

**My problem:**

It happens everytime a user clicks submit. So the #error message returns:

> Please fill in yourfirst name, last name, company, position, first
>   name, last name, company, position, first name, last name, company,
>   position, first name, last name, company, position, first name, last
>   name, company, position, first name, last name, company, position,

**I've looked for other solutions and tried this:**

```
if (input.attr('placeholder').indexOf($('#error')) >= 0){
} else{
     $('#error').append(input.attr('placeholder').toLowerCase() + ', ');
}
```

Is there any way to check if the placeholder text already exists in the #error message? [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YgNT/18/). I'm sorry it's so convoluted. But its what i've been working on and had it handy.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `.indexOf($('#error'))` Why are you passing an object to `indexOf` method?

Comment: `input.attr('placeholder').indexOf($('#error'))` will always be `-1` unless your string contains `[object Object]`, maybe you meant `$("#error').text()`?

Comment: can you overwrite the div contents with .html() or .text() each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8YgNT/20/

```
var errorText = '';

//Validate required fields
for (i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
    var input = $('#' + required[i]);

    if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
        input.addClass("tobefixed");
        errornotice.fadeIn(750);

        if (input.attr('placeholder').indexOf($('#error')) >= 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            errorText = errorText + $(input).attr('placeholder').toLowerCase() + ', ';
        }

        input.val(emptyerror);
        errornotice.fadeIn(750);
    } else {
        input.removeClass("tobefixed");
    }
}

$('#error').html('').append('Please fill in your ' + errorText);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

I simple add one line in your fiddle and it's working now:

```
required = ["id_first_name", "id_last_name", "id_firmbox", "id_job_title"];

errornotice = $("#error");
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";

$("#startform").submit(function(){
//Validate required fields

$("#error").html("Please fill in your");

for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
    var input = $('#'+required[i]);
    if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
        input.addClass("tobefixed");        
        errornotice.fadeIn(750);


        // =====Here===== //
        if (input.attr('placeholder').indexOf($('#error')) >= 0){
        } else{
            $('#error').append(input.attr('placeholder').toLowerCase() + ', ');
        }
        // ============== //



        input.val(emptyerror);
        errornotice.fadeIn(750);
    } else {
        input.removeClass("tobefixed");
    }
 }

 if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
    return false;
 } else {
    errornotice.hide();
    return true;
 }
});
$(":input").focus(function(){
 if ($(this).hasClass("tobefixed") ) {
     $(this).val("");
     $(this).removeClass("tobefixed");
 }
});
```

This line do the all trick:

```
$("#error").html("Please fill in your");
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether `#error` contains the string you're wondering about, you can use

```
($('#error').text().indexOf(a_string)) != -1
```

This will return true if `#error` contains `a_string`.

There's a longer discussion on searching strings for other strings [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing it the wrong way round (and forgetting to get the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) out of the `#error` element):

```
if ( $('#error').text().indexOf( input.attr('placeholder') ) >= 0)
```